# NoTitleNoActionBar theme not hiding Toolbar/ActionBar for Fragment in Android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-theme, android-styles

In the application, main screen has toolbar which has style applied for toolbar. To perform transition effect using fragment which behaves as a dialog with background transparent.
Now, to hide the toolbar/actiobar used following code

```
public void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();
}


@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

}
Now, with this code whole screen goes up in background so jumping screen up slightly and now when to close dialog it re-appear again. so is there any specific way to hide actionbar/toobar for particualr screen. Now, For activity it is easy to hide the actionbar/toolbar with theme specified like;

```
<style name="Theme.project.NoTitleNoActionBar" parent="Theme.project">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
 </style>
```

But when applied to Fragment it doesn't shown any effect set theme using following lines;

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    getActivity().setTheme(R.style.Theme_project_NoTitleNoActionBar);
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}
```

Still the same problem exists. so how to hide actionbar/toolbar for such prolem? any help appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: If you call Activity#setTheme, you should recreate it. So you code has no effect. And i think use Activity#setTheme maybe not  the right way.

Comment: @Kilnn what can be right way ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your styles.xml file inside values folder and add parent tag as Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar. Refer following code for the same

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: why all items contains color change? i need to hide toolbar/actionbar from particular screen ? still will try it, thanks